# Java Non-Binary Tree Pre-Order Traversal

Tags: java, tree

I am having some trouble traversing a non-binary tree and outputting the pre-order enumeration.

The current code I have is:

```
  public String GetPreOrder(ADS2TreeNode root, String res)
  {        
      res += data;
      if (numberOfChildren != 0)
      {
          for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChildren; i++)
          {
              res += "," + children[i];
          }            
      }      
   return res;              
  }


  public String GetPreOrder()
  {  
      String res = "";
      return root.GetPreOrder(root, res);
  }
```

Based on the test data of "(B(E(K),F))"
it outputs B,E(K),F
However it should output B, E, K, F

I believe it is because it simply prints the array which stores the children of E rather than accessing them individually? However I am unsure how to do this.

Could anyone shine any light as to why this is happening and how to solve this?

#

I now have an issue with the following code:

```
 public String GetPreOrder(ADS2TreeNode root, String res)
  {    
      if (root.numberOfChildren == 0)
      {
          res += root.data;
          root = root.parent;
      }
      else
      {


      for (int i = 0; i < root.numberOfChildren; i++)
          {
              res += root.data + ',';
              root = root.getChild(i);
              res = GetPreOrder(root, res);
          }

       }          
        return res;     
  }
```

Whilst debugging it, it loops though each subtree as it should, however it doesn't fully reach the end of the tree - i've spent ages trying to figure it out via debugging but I can't seem to understand why.

Can anyone see the mistake with my code or something I am missing?

Comment: It's not clear how this code is traversing the tree.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is a function `pre-order-traversal(tree)`, it does the following:

1. Visit the root and display its value/content/etc.
2. Visit the first subtree by recursively calling the `pre-order-traversal(tree)` function.
3. Continue with all the other subtrees from left to right, by calling `pre-order-traversal(tree)` recursively.

Your Code does not traverse the subtrees and only (implicitly) calls their `toString()` methods which show the given subtree with its children in parentheses.

Thus, the solution is to recursively call `GetPreOrder(...)` on the children, because they are trees, too.

Your second problem arises because you reset root to be the first child. Hence, in the second iteration of the for-loop not the real root is used, but the first subtrees root. Simply do not reuse the parameter root and use a local variable instead.

```
res += root.data + ',';
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChildren; i++)
{
    ADS2TreeNode child = root.getChild(i);
    res += GetPreOrder(child, res);
}
```

If you were somehow able to access the array from the first part of your question, you could use a for-each-loop which is much nicer.

```
res += root.data + ',';
for(ADS2TreeNode child : children) {
    res += GetPreOrder(child, res);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this has been helpful! Following your advise i've come up with a solution which I'll add to this thread as I have a problem with my current code which I can't understand and I would be very appreciative if you could have a look at it for me?